# get leap seconds from gps data (core location) iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, leap-second

is it possible to get the used leap seconds from the gps data using core location framework?
I need the exact date/time to synchronize an external device over my iPad/iPhone via BTLE.

Thanks, Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. from ios you get UTC time wich already contains the leap seconds difference between UTC and GPS time reference.

But a leap seconds is introduced aprox. once a year.

Now we have 16 or 17s time diff. Either you build a table when the leap seconds have been changed for historical lookup,

Or for current synchronisation you take a fixed value of 16 or 17s (search the exact value via google), and update this value once it changes.

Another solution: You use a web servcie which provdes the current offset between GPS and UTC.

However GPS devices are principially capable of sending the utc leap sec difference, maybe your device unfortunately not.

Comment: GPS is ahead of UTC by 16 seconds since 2012-07-01Z. [iOS uses the tz database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html) that contains [the leap-seconds list](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/leap-seconds.list#L193).